# How to get mouseMovement when cursor is locked?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js, pointerlock

While looking for way to lock the cursor in processing/p5.js/javascript I realized that even once I figured that out I would not be able to detect mouse movement. How do people do it in typical fps games?

Comment: If by "lock the cursor" you mean using the new `Pointer Lock` API, that doesn't seem to be integrated with the p5.js library -- but you can still use it from your sketch since your sketch is just JavaScript code. p5.js.dom might useful for combining p5.js with other JavaScript libraries [See this](https://github.com/shiffman/The-Nature-of-Code-Examples-p5.js/issues/76) for an interesting discussion.

Comment: Yes but if the pointer is locked in the middle... how will it ever move?

Comment: I don't have experience with that API. Perhaps you can focus your question a bit and post it with the `pointerlock` tag (which exists but doesn't seem to have much traffic).

Comment: You use [`movementX/Y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/movementX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You leverage [`movementX/Y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/movementX) which are still updated while the cursor is locked.

See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_Lock_API#locked_state):

> When Pointer lock is enabled, the standard MouseEvent properties
>   clientX, clientY, screenX, and screenY are held constant, as if the
>   mouse is not moving. The movementX and movementY properties continue
>   to provide the mouse's change in position. There is no limit to
>   movementX and movementY values if the mouse is continuously moving in
>   a single direction. The concept of the mouse cursor does not exist and
>   the cursor cannot move off the window or be clamped by a screen edge.

---

**Note that the snippet below will not work on Stack Overflow due to sandboxing restrictions.  See: [iframe limitations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_Lock_API#iframe_limitations)**

```js
const foo = document.getElementById("foo");
const button = document.getElementById("btn");
const dX = document.getElementById("x");
const dY = document.getElementById("y");

function lockPointer(elem) {
  if (elem.requestPointerLock) {
    elem.requestPointerLock();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestPointerLock) {
    elem.webkitRequestPointerLock();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestPointerLock) {
    elem.mozRequestPointerLock();
  } else {
    console.warn("Pointer locking not supported");
  }
}

foo.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  const {
    movementX,
    movementY
  } = e;

  dX.innerHTML = movementX;
  dY.innerHTML = movementY;
});

btn.addEventListener("click", e => {
  lockPointer(foo);
});
```

```css
#foo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="foo"></canvas>
<button id="btn">Lock</button>
<div>X: <span id="x"></span> | Y: <span id="y"></span></div>
```

Comment: I put your snippet in there and it worked fine. I will bookmark this page for later. thanks this is a big help!